# Access plugin instance using the id of the DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

The concept is to have 2 plugins one for form and another for button. I want to bind all forms in my page to JQuery plugin that will handle some jobs let say that this is my plugin

```
$.fn.PluginForm = function (Options) {
var o = jQuery.extend({
    SomeOption: 1
}, Options);

var Validate = function(){
    if(o.SomeOption == 1)  return true;
    else return false;
};

$(this).on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //some code here
});
};
```

The form actually doesn’t have button in my case the post is triggered from another control. This is because of the structure of the application I want to build. The button plugin is:

```
$.fn.PluginButton = function (Options) {
var o = jQuery.extend({
    Actions: [],
    FormID: ''
}, Options);

$(this).click(function(){
    var Form = $('#' + o.FormID);
    if(Form.length > 0 && Form.PluginForm.Validate()) {
        Form.submit();
        //do something
    }
    else{ 
        //do something else
    }
});
};
```

What I want to succeed is to invoke the validation function on the Form element but I don’t want to invoke another instance of the PluginForm. Something like `$('#' + o.FormID).PluginForm.Validate()`

All this must be as plugin because there will be a lot of forms in the same page and a lot of buttons. Also there will be a lot of buttons that can invoke submit on the same form but with different options. That’s why I want to invoke one time the instance of the form. Also the controls that will be validated will be passed as parameter in the options of the PluginForm. Something like this `$('#' + o.FormID).PluginForm({ Action: ‘Validate’ })` is not an option because will lose the initial parameters of the PluginForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the plugin instance in the .data() structure on the element, and then call it back. Most of plugins use it that way.

```
/*!
 * jQuery lightweight plugin boilerplate
 * Original author: @ajpiano
 * Further changes, comments: @addyosmani
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

// the semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety
// net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins
// that are not closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global
    // variable in ECMAScript 3 and is mutable (i.e. it can
    // be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really
    // being passed in so we can ensure that its value is
    // truly undefined. In ES5, undefined can no longer be
    // modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local
    // variables rather than as globals, because this (slightly)
    // quickens the resolution process and can be more
    // efficiently minified (especially when both are
    // regularly referenced in your plugin).

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;

        // jQuery has an extend method that merges the
        // contents of two or more objects, storing the
        // result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty because we don't want to alter
        // the default options for future instances of the plugin
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            // Place initialization logic here
            // You already have access to the DOM element and
            // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
            // and this.options
            // you can add more functions like the one below and
            // call them like so: this.yourOtherFunction(this.element, this.options).
        },

        yourOtherFunction: function(el, options) {
            // some logic
        }
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

taken from: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.basic.plugin-boilerplate.js

also there are more jquery plugin design patterns that may fit more for your plugin at http://jqueryboilerplate.com/.

Comment: Works like a charm. I’m not use to this structure but this is my problem ;). The only thing that if somebody else read this must have in mind is that this.element = element;
Returns DOM Object not JQuery Object 
this.element = $(element);

tnx